# Widget smaller on Nova Launcher but works fine on stock launcher?

Tags: android-widget, android-launcher

I made my first launcher and it worked well till I switched to using Nova launcher instead of the stock TouchWiz launcher. The problem is the widget is cropped at the bottom and things like images on the widget are cut of.
I set my widget to be a 4x2 (250dp x 110dp).
Am I the only one to experience this problem?